# Excel:VBA: How to make script dynamic?

Tags: html, excel, vba

I have the following script:

```
Sub Test1()

Dim IE As Object
Set IE = GetObject("new:{D5E8041D-920F-45e9-B8FB-B1DEB82C6E5E}")

IE.Visible = True
IE.navigate "https://share.amazon.com/sites/IPV/Lists/IPV%20Appeals%20tracker/NewForm.aspx?Source=https%3A%2F%2Fshare%2Eamazon%2Ecom%2Fsites%2FIPV%2FLists%2FIPV%2520Appeals%2520tracker%2FAllItems%2Easpx&RootFolder="

Do While IE.Busy
    Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
Loop

IE.document.getElementById("Title_fa564e0f-0c70-4ab9-b863-0177e6ddd247_$TextField").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1").Range("a1")
IE.document.getElementById("Seller_x0020_ID_2b32b5fa-ace8-44d5-bba5-5c0e321671ed_$TextField").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1").Range("b1")
IE.document.getElementById("Seller_bba5-5c0e321671ed_$TextField").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1").Range("c1")
IE.document.getElementById("Seller_bba5-5c0e321671ed_$TextField").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1").Range("d1")
IE.document.getElementById("Seller_bba5-5c0e321671ed_$TextField").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1").Range("e1")
End Sub
```

This script is suppose to copy the values in the following row range in excel and autofill a website form.
The problem with this is that i have applied it for just the first row, but I wanted a way to be able to select which row to apply this to.

I hope my explanation makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Concatenate in row number e.g.

```
Dim rowNumber As Long

rowNumber = 2

IE.document.getElementById("Title_fa564e0f-0c70-4ab9-b863-0177e6ddd247_$TextField").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1").Range("A" & rowNumber)
```

If using in a loop then you would concatenate in the loop variable and make the id also a variable.

Same principle for your other items.

You could also pick the row number up from a cell

```
IE.document.getElementById("Title_fa564e0f-0c70-4ab9-b863-0177e6ddd247_$TextField").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1").Range("A" & ActiveSheet.Range("A1").value)
```

Avoid ActiveSheet and use the actual sheet name however.

Comment: Thank you very mcuh for your time and helping me with this!